# How can I download and install "amdgpu-pro" drivers for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: amd-graphics, 22.04, ffmpeg, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I'm trying to do H.264 encoding using FFMPEG with AMD AMF hardware acceleration since I have an AMD Radeon RX 580 GPU.

How can I do this?

I installed Ubuntu 22.04

Thanks.

Comment: There can be several setup cases under “Ubuntu 22.04”: proprietary components vs pure open-source, Wayland vs Xorg, etc. Which did you try?